# Do I need to download the dependencies that Spring need in Maven?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, maven

I am starting out with Spring and I am reading `Pro Spring 2.5`. On page 17 they talk about Spring dependencies and I wonder if I need to add this myself in the POM, or does the dependency I have added below do this? Such as CGLib, dom4j etc?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to. Maven will read the pom for spring-context and get any necessary dependencies that it has too, so you won't need to specifically put them in your own pom.

Check out this [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e689) it's really handy.

Comment: So Spring Context is not the complete framework? Do I need to add other things for the link you posted as well in order to use it?

Comment: No - that'll get you started. Spring has multiple packages (e.g. webflow, web-mvc, roo, etc.) which if you want to use you would have to put in your pom specifically. I've updated the link to point directly to the documentation for maven.

Comment: You'll be able to watch maven download the dependencies. Add the info to your `pom` and then run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` (if you're using eclipse) or `mvn clean install`. In the output you will see a bunch of dependencies downloaded (`spring-context`, `spring-aop`, `spring-asm`, etc. etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This will just instruct maven that the current POM in which this is declared is dependent on this artfact, so when you compile the app it would make it available for you in classpath